# Does Alamofire cause this memory leak?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, alamofire

**Leak Image 1**

[image]

**Leak Image 2**

[image]

This leak won't happen on the simulator, but as long as I test leak using instrument on my iPhone it will show up. After checking out my project, I find it only occurs at using Alamofire. This is my code:

```
final func request(_ method:HTTPMethod,urlString:String,parameter:[String:AnyObject]?=nil,success:((JSON)->Void)?,faliure:((AnyObject)->Void)?){
    let relativeURLString = hostUrlString + urlString
    SwiftProgressHUD.shareInstance.showIndicatorHUD()
    Alamofire.request(relativeURLString,method:method,parameters: parameter, headers: getAuthDic())
    .validate()
        .responseJSON(){ response in
            SwiftProgressHUD.shareInstance.remove()
            switch response.result {
            case .success :
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    success!(json)
                }
            case .failure(let error):

                faliure!(error as AnyObject)

            }

    }
}
```

what should i do? It's my problem?